# How to get a full image map, with pan, zoom in, zoom out?

Tags: javascript, css, image, reactjs, maps

I'm looking to get something like [this](https://commenthol.github.io/leaflet-rastercoords/example/index.html).

I've spent a week trying to find a solution to no avail. I am looking for library that can work with React.

The image should not stretch or lose quality when browser is minimised, i should be able to drag/pinch along.

Any advise welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [React Leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet). You can build pretty much anything map-related with it.